# PhoneGap plugins on github - purplecabbage vs phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Which repository is considered the defacto standard source for PhoneGap plugins?

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

or

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins

I see them both referenced in difference places. It looks like there is a lot of duplication but sometimes one is updated and not the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most up to date repo should be https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Comment: +1 - Note the phonegap repo was forked from purplecabbage; likely someone started the ball rolling & phonegap/cordova picked it up/made official'ish.